# How does "git show-branch" command pick short names/labels for commits when multiple options exists?

Tags: git

I am playing with the git show-branch command and have a question regarding the output. When I execute from branch "branch"

```
    git show-branch
```

I get as output:

```
    ! [branch] Add branch_file4
     * [master] Add master_file4
    --
    +  [branch] Add branch_file4
    +  [branch^] Add branch_file3
     * [master] Add master_file4
     * [master^] Add master_file3
    +* [branch~2] Add master_file2
    +* [branch~3] Add master_file1
```

The short names make perfect sense from the perspective of branch "branch".

Now I switch over to branch "master" and get almost the same output:

```
    * [master] Add master_file4
     ! [branch] Add branch_file4
    --
     + [branch] Add branch_file4
     + [branch^] Add branch_file3
    *  [master] Add master_file4
    *  [master^] Add master_file3
    *+ [branch~2] Add master_file2
    *+ [branch~3] Add master_file1
```

Now I would have expected that *[branch~2]* is called *[master~2]*. I know that the short name is just a label to reference the SHA of a commit, so it does not really matter if the label is *[branch~2]* or *[master~2]*, but I wonder how show-branch picks the label when there is multiple possible valid labels.

Comment: Use the source, Luke.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it goes by the first parent in the list of the commit's parents.

Check out the [Git source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/show-branch.c). Specifically, look at the `name-commits` function therein.